# Python Add python package to aws layer using CDK not working

Tags: amazon-web-services, aws-lambda, aws-cdk, aws-lambda-layers, python-3.11

I'm trying to add pandas to my aws layer using aws CDK so my aws function can use this layer. However, upon testing the lambda function I get the following error:

```
{
  "errorMessage": "module 'pandas' has no attribute 'show_versions'",
  "errorType": "AttributeError",
  "requestId": "55a21990-a693-44df-b80c-03f497c4e7ee",
  "stackTrace": [
    "  File \"/var/task/pandas.py\", line 5, in lambda_handler\n    pd.show_versions()\n"
  ]
}
```

Here is an overview of my project structure:

```
- project
  - .venv/**
  - stack
    - pandas_stack.py
  - layers
    - python/lib/python3.11/site-packages
  - lambda
    - pandas_lambda.py
```

In my pandas_lambda.py I have the following code:

```
import json
import pandas as pd

def lambda_handler(event, context):
  pd.show_versions()
  return 1
```

In my pandas_stack.py I have the following code:

```
from constructs import Construct
from aws_cdk import (
    Stack,
    aws_lambda as _lambda
)

class PandasStack(Stack):

    def __init__(self, scope: Construct, construct_id: str, **kwargs) -> None:
        super().__init__(scope, construct_id, **kwargs)

        lambdaLayer = _lambda.LayerVersion(self, 'lambda-layer',
            code = _lambda.AssetCode('layers/'),
            compatible_runtimes = [_lambda.Runtime.PYTHON_3_11]
        )   

        lambdaFn = _lambda.Function(
            self, 'lambda-function',
            runtime=_lambda.Runtime.PYTHON_3_11,
            code=_lambda.Code.from_asset('lambda'),
            handler='pandas.lambda_handler',
            function_name='lambda_pandas_handler',
            description='Lambda function deployed using AWS CDK Python',
            layers = [lambdaLayer]
        )
```

The package pandas I installed in the folder `layers/python/lib/python3.11/site-packages` using the following command: `.venv/bin/pip3 install pandas -t ./layers/python/lib/python3.11/site-packages`

I checked the AWS Management Console to check if my layer is added correctly to the AWS Lambda Function. This happens to be the case:
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/2ZrmV.png)

I downloaded the Lambda Layer to check the contents of the layer. The contents of the layer is this:
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/3k0bk.png)

Not quite sure what I'm missing here! Anybody knows what's wrong?
Thanks in advance!

Comment: You could try using `dir` to see which attributes it has. But it would be a good idea to switch to the `PythonFunction` construct.

Answer (score 0):

I would suggest either of the two following approaches :

- like already suggested, switch to `PythonFunction`, and instead of manually installing pandas in a `layer` folder, you can simply list that requirement in a `requirements.txt` file that you place in `project/lambda` and CDK does the rest of the work.
- if you stick with your approach, I'd first check that `pandas` is actually properly installed locally. I would inspect `layers/python/lib/python3.11/site-packages`. Is the content what you expect? Your lambda seems to be detecting the `pandas` package but not one of its basic function `show_versions`, which suggests it wasn't installed properly. Another way to check the dependencies of your lambda is to go on the console (probably can do it on the CLI as well), go to your lambda's page and in 'actions', export your lambda's deps in a zip file locally. You can then inspect the `pandas` module.